# Merging matrices using label vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have the following data.

- a row vector idx1 of length n1
- an m x n1 matrix A1
- a row vector idx2 of length n2
- an m x n2 matrix A2

The row vectors idx1 and idx2 label the columns of A1 and A2, respectively. Essentially, I want to merge the columns of A1 and A2 according to the labels in idx1 and idx2. I think it's easiest to give some code I already have that does the job.

```
idx = union(idx1,idx2);
A = zeros(size(A1,1),length(idx));
for i = 1:length(idx)
    j1 = find(idx1 == idx(i),1);
    if ~isempty(j1)
        A(:,i) = A(:,i) + A1(:,j1);
    end
    j2 = find(idx2 == idx(i),2);
    if ~isempty(j2)
        A(:,i) = A(:,i) + A2(:,j2);
    end
end
```

Now, my problem is that I want to carry out this operation efficiently, sometimes on sparse matrices. Is there a faster way than what I have? Does the answer change if A1 and A2 are sparse?

Comment: Should we assume `idx1` has no repeated values, and same for `idx2`? Otherwise I think your code doesn't work

Comment: We can assume that idx1 and idx2 are sorted vectors of positive integers, and contain no repeated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform the addition with an entire array (at the cost of two calls to `ismember`:

```
idx = union(idx1,idx2);
A = zeros(size(A1,1),length(idx));

[~,loc1] = ismember(idx1,idx);
[~,loc2] = ismember(idx2,idx);

A(:,loc1) = A(:,loc1) + A1;
A(:,loc2) = A(:,loc2) + A2;
```

Comment: doesn't this require that idx1 and idx2 are sorted?

Comment: @bdecaf: no - the use of the `loc` output argument takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks for the input! But I find this is about 40% slower than my code. In R2009b, I used tic/toc to time 1000 repetitions of both methods on a small example, and my code ran in 0.1295s, while your code ran in 0.1833s.

Comment: After running more tests, it seems like this version can be quite a bit faster when A1 and A2 are sparse.

Comment: @Stirling: if the indices are sorted, you can call `ismembc` instead of ismember to skip two additional sorting steps.

Answer (score 1):

If `idx1` and `idx2` contain integer values, you can put the `sparse` function to do the sum for you:

```
[ii1 jj1] = ndgrid(1:m, idx1);
[ii2 jj2] = ndgrid(1:m, idx2);
A = sparse([ii1 ii2],[jj1 jj2],[A1 A2]); %// do the sum for matching indices
A = A(:,union(idx1, idx2)); %// result in sparse form
A = full(A); %// optional
```